# How to assign serial as a primary key for the existing data?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in the postgres for which I dint assign any primary key as the values are repeated, but now I want to add primary key for it by altering the table and adding serial column as a primary key . Will it allow me to do that, will it assign the serial numbers for the existing data after I alter the table? What would be the best practice to do that?

Comment: Please fix spelling. This will help make the question easy to understand and find for other users in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table t
add column i serial primary key;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html